# How to create xml document as a property in c#.net

Tags: c#

I wants to set a xml document as a property, where user can set the values of xml attributes and tags but can not change the xml formate. user will not be allowed to delete or add any node in that xml.

Can any body help me out of this ?

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you looking for some UI that can do this?

Comment: No, i want's to create a class library for front-end developer. where they don't require to create a xml for any database transaction. The xml and database is on my side, they just have to provide the values required.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways of doing this. If the data contained in the xml document can be translated into a serializable class (default constructor, getters and setters for all properties - since the data is xml anyway, it's probably trivially serializable) , you can simply expose the document like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyDocument
{
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = False)]
    public int Property1 { get; set }

    [XmlArray(IsNullable= False)]
    public List<string> Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

This allows you to use the XmlSerializer class to load and save documents to disk, IO streams etc. without having to directly interact with the Xml DOM. Setting IsNullable to false means that when serialization takes place, a node will always be generated, or an exception thrown.

Otherwise, you can create a wrapper around the document, like so:

```
public class MyDocument
{
    private XDocument the_document = null;

    public string Property1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.the_document... //getter DOM manipulation here
        }
        set
        {
           if(value == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));

           this.the_document... = value //setter DOM manipulation here
        }
    }
}
```

Either way, your aim is to hide the flexibility of the XML document from the user, and use an accessor class you have written to manipulate the elements you want to change.

If the document has an xsd, your task can be even easier - xsd.exe will allow you to automatically generate Seralizable C# classes from a given xsd schema.